# Laravel 4 - Process via controller after validating in routes file

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Im having a little trouble getting used to the whole routes and controllers in Laravel 4.

From my understanding, routes should only be used to decide where to point the URL so it shouldnt be used to process uploads or anything like that.

So basically what i have is my routes file which validates the user fields, then how do i point it to a controller to process teh uploads and everything like that.

I currently have the following code, but when the validation passes and it should go to the controller file, it just displays a blank screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Route::post('create-profile', function()
{

// Validation rules
$rules = array(
    'username' => 'required|unique:users,username|min:4|alpha_dash',
    'emailaddress' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
    'country' => 'required',
    'state' => 'required',
    'genre' => 'required',
    'filename' => 'image',
    'password' => 'required|min:5|confirmed',
    'password_confirmation' => 'required'
);

// Validate the inputs
$v = Validator::make( Input::all(), $rules );

// Was the validation successful?
if ( $v->fails() )
{

    // Something went wrong
    return Redirect::to('create-profile')->withErrors( $v )->withInput(Input::except('password', 'password_confirmation'));

} else {

            // Here is where it seems to all go wrong.
    Route::get('create-profile', 'CreateProfileController@processSignup');

}

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your url will be:

```
http://site.com/create-profile
```

What I'm showing is not ideal, but I think that your code should look more like the one below:

routes.php

```
<?php

Route::post('create-profile', 'CreateProfileController@processSignup');
Route::get('create-profile', 'CreateProfileController@signup');
```

CreateProfileController.php

```
<?php

Class CreateProfileController extends Controller {

    public function processSignup()
    {

        // Validation rules
        $rules = array(
            'username' => 'required|unique:users,username|min:4|alpha_dash',
            'emailaddress' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'country' => 'required',
            'state' => 'required',
            'genre' => 'required',
            'filename' => 'image',
            'password' => 'required|min:5|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required'
        );

        // Validate the inputs
        $v = Validator::make( Input::all(), $rules );

        // Was the validation successful?
        if ( $v->fails() )
        {
            // Something went wrong
            return Redirect::to('create-profile')->withErrors( $v )->withInput(Input::except('password', 'password_confirmation'));
        }

        return View::make('success');
    }

    public function signup()
    {
        return View::make('signup');    
    }   
}
```

It's better to have all your routes pointing to controllers actions and let them do the job and, also, it's a little more readable and easy to understand.

Using resource controllers, you can reduce your routes names:

```
Route::resource('profile', 'ProfileController', array('only' => array('create', 'store')));
```

Wich will give you those routes:

```
http://site.com/profile/create
http://site.com/profile/store
```

Comment: Thank you for that .. What do you mean that it's not ideal?

Comment: My answer was not ideal, I mean. Take a look at resouce controllers: http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers. Unless you really need routes for something different from a normal get and post crud, they are better.

Comment: Oh thats interesting, so for a signup form using resource controller, i would only need the index and store resource actions ... is that right?

Comment: Exactly. Also, check the `php artisan routes` command, gives you a pretty good view of all your routes.

Comment: Actually, you'll need create and store. Index is for showing all your resources, in a list or something like that. Create is your form, store the form post.

Comment: Sorry, i dont really understand that ... what do you mean index is for showing resources?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, specially this table: http://puu.sh/3daPq.png, I think it will be better to understand it all.

Comment: Ok, so based on the table, new = create and create = store for L4 ?

Comment: Yeah, names will differ from framework to framework but this is the basic list of routes and actions of a resourceful controller.

Comment: Ok, i will give these resource controllers a go .. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: No problem. Give a try to #laravel at Freenode IRC server, it's a helpful community.

Comment: There is one problem, using the create route, means that the form will have to sit on www.site.com/create-profile/create ... so to get it to show on just the /create-profile/ url i should use the index and store?

Comment: Not really sure if I understood your concern. But you don't have to think much about your urls, just your routes, from now on you can create them using URL::route('create-profile.create') or, if you use a shorter resource form like `Route::resource('profile','ProfileController');`, it will be `URL::route('profile.create')` and yes, you won't be using the /create-profile/ url (or /profile/ url), but /create-profile/ (or, /profile/create/, using the shorte one, a little bit more natural and in the end similar to yours). I just added an edit to clarify.

Comment: Yes, i tried that .. When i created controller i told it to only add teh create and store ... but when i went to www.site.com/create-profile it gave me an error, it wasnt until i went to www.site.com/create-profile/create it showed it ... i dont want the /create on the end just to see the form when i go to www.site.com/create-profile

Comment: If the validation succeeds it is better to redirect to a another GET route and show a view from there. It is a good practice to never serve views on POST (or PUT/DELETE/PATCH) routes.